# How will be get unique identifiers of activities from Health app in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am getting data from HealthKit but i want to get unique ids of all activities that coming from HealthKit to send that id to the server and save that activity against that particular id. Is there a unique id for these?

Comment: Minor edits for legibility.

Comment: Yeah i am talking about each workout for example running or swimming etc

Answer (score 2):

The `uuid` [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobject/1615721-uuid) of `HKObject` uniquely identifies each object in HealthKit.

Answer (score 0):

From an object of HKWorkout, you can get an ID like this:

```
workout.uuid.uuidString
```